# Is it possible to replace if-else with switch statement using strings as switching values?

Tags: java, action, switch-statement

I'm wondering if it's possible to use switch statement instead of if-else one in this case. Variables are taken from JComboBoxes and processed by ActionEvent here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    Object source = event.getSource();

     if (source == comboUnit) {

        String unit = comboUnit.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (unit.equals("Unit 1")) {
            unitValue = Double.parseDouble(tfUnit.getText());
            valMeter = unitValue * defined1;
            labelDesc.setText("Unit 1");
            convert();
        }

        else if (unit.equals("Unit 2")) {
            unitValue = Double.parseDouble(tfUnit.getText());
            valMeter = unitValue * defined2;
            labelDesc.setText("Unit 2");
            convert();
        }
(...)
```

I was trying to pass pure strings as the values but with no success. Do you have any hints on how it should be done (and if it's even possible)?

Comment: Any specific reason why would you want switch-case?

Comment: The only reason is to make the code more clear.

Comment: then, as dystroy says down below, move all the common code into the main bit of the `if (source == comboUnit)` condition and just have the `valmeter = ` lines in the if statement (`labelDesc.setText(unit);` will work in the common code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 7 allows you to `switch` on `String`s.

Your code needs refactoring though, and the question of whether to use `switch` or [enumerations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) or [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), is something that comes second, I would say.

You have too much duplicated code doing essentially the same thing. I am referring to:

```
unitValue = Double.parseDouble(tfUnit.getText());
valMeter = unitValue * defined1;
labelDesc.setText("Unit 1");
convert();
```

Obviously, because you multiply using different factors depending on the unit used, you need a function of unit evaluating to the factor to use. In less mathematical terms, you need something that yields value of either `defined1` or `defined2` depending on a string supplied.  You already have the `unit` referring to the "name" of your unit in question, you can use it. I call the method returning the factor for `factor`, taking in a unit name and returning a `Number` (since it does not follow from your example whether you are multiplying integers or real numbers of some sort). I am also assuming your `defined1` and `defined2` etc, are variables or literals.

```
unitValue = Double.parseDouble(tfUnit.getText());
valMeter = unitValue * factor(unit);
labelDesc.setText(unit);
convert();

Number factor(String unitName) {
     switch(unitName) {
         case "Unit 1": return defined1;
         case "Unit 2": return defined2;
         default: throw new Exception("Unknown unit");
     }
}
```

The method itself is where your "to switch or not to switch" problem creeps in. You are free to use a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) if you want:

```
Map<String, Number> unitNameValueMap = new HashMap<String, Number>();

unitNameValueMap.put("Unit 1", defined1);
unitNameValueMap.put("Unit 2", defined2);

Number factor(String unitName) {
    Number result = unitNameValueMap.get(unitName);
    if(result == null) throw new Exception("Unknown unit");
    return result;
}
```

Or you can use enumerations:

```
enum UnitValue {
    UNIT1(defined1), UNIT2(defined2);
    final Number value;
    private UnitValue(Number value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

Number factor(String unitName) {
    return Enum.valueOf(UnitValue.class, "UNIT" + Integer.parseInt(unitName.substring(5)).value;
}
```

You can even `switch` or use a map inside enumerations, which will give you good code readability as well.

You need to profile your program to see if you need `switch`-based solution or enum-based one or a map-based one. The way it currently stands and as you can see for yourself, the `enum`-based solution is a bit messy because of relationship between your unit names, enumeration constants, and their values. If someone can do better with enums, then take their code instead, naturally.

Usually, shortest code is best, as it is easier to read and most often understand. But be careful with maps - they induce more overhead than other solutions, so I for one prefer to use them where I have fewer maps with many keys each, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum` and replace string with Enum values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Units unit = Units.Unit1;
    switch (unit) {
    case Unit1:
        break;
    case Unit2:
        break;
    }
}

enum Units {
    Unit1, Unit2,
}
```

Java 7 allows you [Using Strings in switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
switch (unit) {
case "Unit 1":
  // do something
  break;

case "Unit 2":

}
```

?

Yes you can, starting with Java7.

But in your case, you don't seem to need neither switch nor if/else. You do the same thing in both cases :

```
 String unit = comboUnit.getSelectedItem().toString();
 unitValue = Double.parseDouble(tfUnit.getText());
 valMeter = unitValue * defined1;
 labelDesc.setText(unit);
 convert();
```

Comment: @dys: nahh, valmeter involves defined1 or defined2

Comment: And can't it be obtained more simply ? I suggest at least to put all that you can outside the switch and leave only the code that really depends on the unit.

Answer (score 0):

Only in Java 7 and later is it possible to use Strings in a switch-case statement. Here is a link to the documentation, you will need to scroll down to the String section.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html